# Accessing Python object in tuple

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am using easyzone and dnspython to extract DNS records from a zone file. When extracting A records I am given back a string and an object in a tuple. I am new to Python coming from PHP and am not quite sure how to get at this object to get the value of it? I had no problems getting the string value in the tuple.

In this code snippet I iterate through the A records and write the values into a CSV:

```
    # Write all A records
    for a in z.names.items():
        c.writerow([domain, 'A', a.__getitem__(0), a])
```

a contains the following:

```
('www.121dentalcare.com.', <easyzone.easyzone.Name object at 0x1012dd190>)
```

How would I access this object within a which is in the 2nd half of this tuple??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use indices to get items from a tuple:

```
sometuple[1]
```

just as you can do with lists and strings (see [sequence types](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange)).

The [documentation of `easyzone`](http://www.psychofx.com/easyzone/) is a little on the thin side, but from looking at the [source code](https://bitbucket.org/chrismiles/easyzone/src) it appears the `easyzone.easyzone.Name` objects have `.name`, `.soa` and `.ttl` attributes:

```
print sometuple[1].name
```

The `.soa` attribute is another custom class, with `.mname`, `.rname`, `.serial`, `.refresh`, `.retry`, `.expire` and `.minttl` properties.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that tuple indices (indeed all indices in python) start at 0

Comment: Excellent, now I can isolate that object with a[1] and it returns <easyzone.easyzone.Name object at 0x1012dd2d0> when entered in the CSV. Is there anything like var_dump in PHP for Python, there is an IP inside this object but I am unsure on how to get at the contents of the object or discover its structure?

Comment: @xXPhenom22Xx You can inspect objects with `dir` (gets attributes) and a few other (more specialized) functions. Alternatively ask the documentation. The latter is generally better, because it tells if what's the intended way, can mention caveats/deprecations/alternatives/etc. and doesn't leave you relying on implementation details which change with the next minor release...

Comment: @delnan: documentation, in this case, is close to non-existent, from what I can make out.

Comment: Yea I could only find an example or two on this library with no API reference of any kind. Thanks again for the pointers gentleman!

Comment: @xXPhenom22Xx: The `z.root` object in the examples given is a `Name` object, so the `.records()` call examples shown there apply.

Comment: Martijn thanks so much, was able to get at the contents of the object with the following: a[1].records('A').items.


Thanks again for your help!